# What is the easiest/fastest way to find out when a git branch was created?

Tags: git, branch

I was trying to find out when a certain feature branch in one of my repositories was created and I found that surprisingly hard. I ended up using a combination of `git show-branch` and `git log`.

Is there any easier way to find this little piece of information quickly and efficiently from the command line?

Comment: [How to determine when a Git branch was created?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2255416/995714), [find out when a git branch was created](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18277841/995714)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine when a Git branch was created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255416/how-to-determine-when-a-git-branch-was-created)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
git show $(git merge-base master your-branch)
```

will show the commit where your branch branched off master

Comment: I believe this only works if `your-branch` hasn't been merged with `master`. If this is the case, then won't this show when the branch was last merged?

Comment: @MichaelMior: yes, correct. But with Git if your branch has been merged, you cannot know if it was the same branch or a different branch (You might as well have created a new branch on top of the old one). You will only get the most current (meaningful) merge-base. Think of _branch_ as _not contained in trunk (master)_