# How can I determine when a Git branch was created?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

Is there a way to determine ***when*** a Git branch was created?

I have a branch in my repository, and and I don't remember creating it and thought maybe seeing the creation timestamp would jog my memory.

Comment: found this that was very helpful http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2345/show-git-branches-by-date-useful-for-showing-active-branches

Comment: When you asked this question, were you really just interested in getting the date and time of creation of the branch, or were you also interested in knowing *where* in your commit history the branch was first created, i.e. which commit your branch was first branched off from?

Comment: @Cupcake, the question is pretty clear. I was interested in when I created the branch. That said knowing the commit would be handy information in the general case.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Use

```
git show --summary `git merge-base foo master`
```

If you’d rather see it in context using [gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk), then use

```
gitk --all --select-commit=`git merge-base foo master`
```

(where *foo* is the name of the branch you are looking for.)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: To clarify the answer, there are two steps to the process. (1) get the treesh using "git merge-base <branch> master" where branch is the branch of interest. (2) Use the treesh as input into git show to get the date: "git show --summary <treesh>"

Comment: This answer seems to except that the branch has been created from master. But what if it's not the case ? Is there a way to find the first commit of the branch having more than 1 child ?

Comment: This is not the date at which the branch was _created_ -- this is the "branching" commit.

Comment: The solution will only work if 'branch' was never merged back to 'master'. Is there a way to find the very first merge base for two branches universally?

Comment: @ceretullis, I'm new to the term "treesh". Is that a mash-up of _tree_ and _hash_?

Comment: @user46874 The term used in the git docs is tree-ish, one of many ways to identify a particular tree in a repo. See [Git Tools - Revision Selection](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) or [git treeishes considered awesome](http://highgroove.com/articles/2012/01/19/git-treeishes-considered-awesome.html).

Comment: This is showing the merge base, not branch creation.

Comment: This answer assumes a lot of things, which can be not true (including branch name `master`) and doesn't answers the question

Comment: This command works only from GitBash, and does not work from Windows Cmd

Answer (score 222):

As [pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255416/how-to-determine-when-a-git-branch-was-created?answertab=votes#comment3963677_3748722) and in [Jackub's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2256267/456814), as long as your branch is younger than the number of days set in the config setting `gc.reflogexpire` (the default is 90 days), then you can utilize your reflog to find out when a branch reference was first created.

Note that [`git reflog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) can take most [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) flags. Further note that the `HEAD@{0}` style selectors are effectively notions of time and, in fact, are handled (in a hacked sort of way) as date strings. This means that you can use the flag `--date=local` and get output like this:

```
$ git reflog --date=local
763008c HEAD@{Fri Aug 20 10:09:18 2010}: pull : Fast-forward
f6cec0a HEAD@{Tue Aug 10 09:37:55 2010}: pull : Fast-forward
e9e70bc HEAD@{Thu Feb 4 02:51:10 2010}: pull : Fast forward
836f48c HEAD@{Thu Jan 21 14:08:14 2010}: checkout: moving from master to master
836f48c HEAD@{Thu Jan 21 14:08:10 2010}: pull : Fast forward
24bc734 HEAD@{Wed Jan 20 12:05:45 2010}: checkout: moving from 74fca6a42863ffacaf7ba6f1936a9f228950f657 
74fca6a HEAD@{Wed Jan 20 11:55:43 2010}: checkout: moving from master to v2.6.31
24bc734 HEAD@{Wed Jan 20 11:44:42 2010}: pull : Fast forward
964fe08 HEAD@{Mon Oct 26 15:29:29 2009}: checkout: moving from 4a6908a3a050aacc9c3a2f36b276b46c0629ad91 
4a6908a HEAD@{Mon Oct 26 14:52:12 2009}: checkout: moving from master to v2.6.28
```

It may also be useful at times to use `--date=relative`:

```
$ git reflog --date=relative
763008c HEAD@{4 weeks ago}: pull : Fast-forward
f6cec0a HEAD@{6 weeks ago}: pull : Fast-forward
e9e70bc HEAD@{8 months ago}: pull : Fast forward
836f48c HEAD@{8 months ago}: checkout: moving from master to master
836f48c HEAD@{8 months ago}: pull : Fast forward
24bc734 HEAD@{8 months ago}: checkout: moving from 74fca6a42863ffacaf7ba6f1936a9f228950f657 to master
74fca6a HEAD@{8 months ago}: checkout: moving from master to v2.6.31
24bc734 HEAD@{8 months ago}: pull : Fast forward
964fe08 HEAD@{11 months ago}: checkout: moving from 4a6908a3a050aacc9c3a2f36b276b46c0629ad91 to master
4a6908a HEAD@{11 months ago}: checkout: moving from master to v2.6.28
```

One last note: the `--all` flag (which is really a git-log flag understood by git-reflog) will show the reflogs for all known refs in `refs/` (instead of simply, `HEAD`) which will show you branch events clearly:

```
git reflog --date=local --all
860e4e4 refs/heads/master@{Sun Sep 19 23:00:30 2010}: commit: Second.
17695bc refs/heads/example_branch@{Mon Sep 20 00:31:06 2010}: branch: Created from HEAD
```

Comment: Very interesting. +1. Provided, of course, this takes place within `gc.reflogexpire` days.

Comment: @VonC — right you are. The default value for gc.reflogexpire is 90 days.

Comment: It's important to note that `reflog` only pertains to a _local_ repo's history so it won't help when the branch was created elsewhere and _pulled_.  In that case you can only find out when you pulled the branch.

Answer (score 96):

[Pro Git § 3.1 Git Branching - What a Branch Is](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is) has a good explanation of what a Git branch really is:

> A branch in Git is simply a lightweight movable pointer to [a] commit.

Since a branch is just a lightweight pointer, Git doesn't have any explicit notion of its history or creation date. "But hang on," I hear you say, "of course Git knows my branch history!" Well, sort of.

If you run either of the following:

```
git log <branch> --not master
gitk <branch> --not master
```

you will see what looks like the "history of your branch", but it is really a list of commits reachable from 'branch' that are not reachable from *master*. This gives you the information you want, but if and only if you have never merged 'branch' back to *master*, and have never merged *master* into 'branch' since you created it. If you *have* merged, then this history of differences will collapse.

Fortunately, the reflog often contains the information you want, as explained in various other answers here. Use this:

```
git reflog --date=local <branch>
```

to show the history of the branch. The last entry in this list is (probably) the point at which you created the branch.

If the branch has been deleted then 'branch' is no longer a valid git identifier, but you can use this instead, which may find what you want:

```
git reflog --date=local | grep <branch>
```

Or in a Windows cmd shell:

```
git reflog --date=local | find "<branch>"
```

Note that reflog won't work effectively on remote branches, only ones you have worked on locally.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how useful this answer is yet, I'll need to study it more later. For what it's worth, though, you definitely did a good job of putting in the effort to write something **comprehensive**, and not just a short, lazy partial answer, so that's definitely good. Also, it's important to note that you can only use the reflog for this as long as your branch is not older than `gc.reflogexpire` days, as pointed out in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2256267/456814) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3748722/456814).

Comment: I didn't want to duplicate all the good information about reflogs from the other answers, but happy to add the gc.reflogexpire if you think it's useful. My answer was intended to (1) provide more clarity on what a git branch is and why its "history" is somewhat nebulous, (2) put useful commands front and center, including (3) showing commits on a branch and not master and (4) grep-ing the reflog for a deleted branch. Feedback welcome.

Comment: Thanks @Cupcake. Funnily enough I originally had angle brackets around 'branch' but that was stripping the entire word out of my answer preview, so I assumed it was mistakenly treated as (invalid) inline html.

Comment: This method worked well via intellij and BitBucket `git reflog --date=local <branch>`

Comment: Actually only `git reflog --date=local <branch>` does show `branch: created from HEAD`. The `git log` intersection in addition is very useful to see whether this is a merged or still empty branch. In my opinion this is the best answer.

Answer (score 47):

First, if your branch was created within `gc.reflogexpire` days (default 90 days, i.e., around three months), you can use `git log -g <branch>` or `git reflog show <branch>` to find the first entry in reflog, which would be the creation event, and looks something like below (for `git log -g`):

```
Reflog: <branch>@{<nn>} (C R Eator <creator@example.com>)
Reflog message: branch: Created from <some other branch>
```

You would get who created a branch, how many operations ago, and from which branch (well, it might be just "Created from HEAD", which doesn't help much).

That is what [MikeSep said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255416/howto-determine-when-a-git-branch-was-created/2255538#2255538).

---

Second, if you have branch for longer than `gc.reflogexpire` and you have run `git gc` (or it was run automatically), you would have to find common ancestor with the branch it was created from.  Take a look at config file, perhaps there is `branch.<branchname>.merge` entry, which would tell you what branch this one is based on.

If you know that the branch in question was created off master branch (forking from master branch), for example, you can use the following command to see common ancestor:

```
git show $(git merge-base <branch> master)
```

You can also try `git show-branch <branch> master`, as an alternative.

This is what [gbacon said in his response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255416/howto-determine-when-a-git-branch-was-created/2255638#2255638).

Comment: "git reflog show <branch>" works well, very explicitly shows when the branch was created. Treesh feeds into "git show --summary <treesh>"

Comment: The 'git log -g <branch>' was the one that worked for me - lots of detail.  Need to be on the branch to use any of these.

Answer (score 20):

I'm not sure of the Git command for it yet, but I think you can find them in the reflogs.

```
.git/logs/refs/heads/<yourbranch>
```

My files appear to have a Unix timestamp in them.

There appears to be an option to use the reflog history instead of the commit history when printing the logs:

```
git log -g
```

You can follow this log as well, back to when you created the branch. `git log` is showing the date of the commit, though, not the date when you made the action that made an entry in the reflog. I haven't found that yet, except by looking in the actual reflog in the path above.

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
  git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname)'
```

Comment: I piped this through `| cut -c 5- | sort -r |` and then piped through grep for the month, giving me a list lin reverse chronological order, more or less.

Comment: @Noumenon: for-each-ref can sort for you, by adding e.g. `--sort='-committerdate'` (note the '-' before committerdate for reverse chronological order).

Answer (score 14):

Use:

```
git reflog
```

to show all the living cycles of your repository in the current folder.
The branch name that first appears (from down to up) is the source that was created.

```
855a3ce HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from development to feature-sut-46
855a3ce HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from feature-sut-46 to development
855a3ce HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from feature-jira35 to feature-sut-46
535dd9d HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from feature-sut-46 to feature-jira35
855a3ce HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from development to feature-sut-46
855a3ce HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from feature-jira35 to development
535dd9d HEAD@{6}: commit: insert the format for vendor specific brower - screen.css
855a3ce HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from development to feature-jira35
855a3ce HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from master to development
```

That means:

- Branch development is created (checkout -b) from master
- Branch feature-jira35 is created (checkout -b) from development
- Branch feature-jira-sut-46 is created (checkout -b) from development

Comment: but where are the dates? and you see checking-out to every branch many times. Does this mean only the FIRST occurrence each branch is its creation?

Comment: What do you mean by *"all the living cycles"*?

Answer (score 14):

**This** did it for me: (10 years later)

```
git log [--remotes] --no-walk --decorate
```

Since there is no stored information on branch creation times, what this does is display the first commit of each branch (`--no-walk`), which includes the date of the commit. Use `--remotes` for the remote branches, or omit it for local branches.

Since I do at least one commit in a branch before creating another one, this permitted me trace back a few months of branch creations (and feature dev-start) for documentation purposes.

[source: AnoE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3321/what-git-command-could-be-used-to-check-when-a-remote-branch-was-created) on stackexchange

Comment: @JqueryToAddNumbers For me as well. It showed the *last* commit and not the *first*.

Comment: Did lists every branches, however showing the last commit of each branch

Comment: But "`[`" and "`]`" are not literal? Perhaps explain that in your answer?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 3 years ago"*

Comment: Is this a ***bogus answer***? Re *"display the first commit of each branch"*:  It seems to display the ***last*** commit of each branch, not the ***first*** (with or without `--remotes`).

Comment: Perhaps somebody else can chime in regarding the accuracy of this answer?

Answer (score 12):

#### How to know via the GitHub GUI

I show all the answers and no one gave an answer with the UI. If anyone likes to see when the branch is created via the GitHub UI.

1. Go to the Insights Tab.
2. Select the *Network* tab in the sidebar.

You can see the branch creation like as below

[image]

Comment: The "Network" is not available for the Github free version. Only paid.

Comment: What is "GitHub GUI"? The web interface? [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/)? Something else?

Comment: Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67817240/edit) a reference to it? (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)

Answer (score 10):

This command shows the creation date of branch *dev* from *main*:

```
git reflog show --date=iso dev
```

Output:

```
7a2b33d dev@{2012-11-23 13:20:28 -2100}: branch: Created from main
```

Comment: "the created date of branch"... if less than 90 days. If it was created *more* than 90 days, that information would be purged. As mentioned above in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3748722/6309.

Comment: @Sazzad Hissain Khan This one worked for us as we wanted to provide 'friendly cheat-sheet tips' to some non-technical folk who were getting a little lost with some of the intricacies of Git.

Answer (score 9):

syntax:

`git reflog --date=local | grep checkout: | grep ${current_branch} | tail -1`

example:

`git reflog --date=local | grep checkout: | grep dev-2.19.0 | tail -1`

result:

`cc7a3a8ec HEAD@{Wed Apr 29 14:58:50 2020}: checkout: moving from dev-2.18.0 to dev-2.19.0`

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me (logged me checking out the new branch).  Hint: You can replace `${current_branch}` with `HEAD` for the currently checked out branch, or `$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)` if you want to spell the branch name out to better prevent potential false positives with grep.

Comment: This works for me. Clean and to the point. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is something that I came up with before I found this question.

```
git reflog show --date=local --all | sed 's!^.*refs/!refs/!' | grep '/master' | tail -1
git reflog show --date=local --all | sed 's!^.*refs/!refs/!' | grep 'branch:'
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the best way:
I always check the latest branch created by this way

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/heads/
```

Answer (score 2):

Combined with [the answer from Andrew Sohn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255416/how-can-i-determine-when-a-git-branch-was-created/14265207#14265207):

```
branchcreated=$(git reflog show --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --all | sed 's!^.*refs/!refs/!' | grep '/master' | tail -1| cut -d'{' -f 2| cut -d'}' -f 1 | xargs)
echo $branchcreated
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the details for all the branches

```
for i in `git branch -r | tail -n +2 ` ; do git log --reverse $i | grep -A 2 -B 2 `echo $i | awk -F'origin/' '{print $2}'` | head -n 4 ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just checking the [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash value of the original revision:

[image]

([Source](https://devhints.io/git-revisions))

It could be simplified and use `git log --oneline master..fix`.

Comment: How does that answer the question? There isn't ***any*** date information in the output of that command line.

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow are expected to be comprehensive and not mere hints. They can also include examples. Here is [a real-world repository](https://github.com/Keychron/qmk_firmware/tree/wireless_playground/keyboards/keychron/q1_pro) (for example, branch *"wireless_playground"*).