# Git command to identify source from where a particular branch was created

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm using Bitbucket and want to know the source branch from where this specific branch was created. Is there any git command that can give the name of the parent branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine the source branch of a particular branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374564/how-do-i-determine-the-source-branch-of-a-particular-branch)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the parent branch of a Git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-git-branch)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
1) git log --oneline --graph --color --all --decorate
// Using this command you will get all git log in command line

2) gitk --all
// This is GUI based solution, you need to download gitk library for this
```

Comment: thanks, but this command would give me the commit history for this particular branch, but I don't see the name of the parent branch showing up in the log