# How to tell which branch was my branch derived from?

Tags: git, branch

Some time ago I derived a branch `A` from another branch `X`, and forgot what was `X`. Since that I made a few changes, including merging `master` into `A`, pushed it, etc. Now, how do I find out where I started from, what is `X`? I tried `git log --graph`, but due to the massive number of branches contributing to `master` that was merged into `A`, it's hard to tell where `A` started from.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine the source branch of a particular branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374564/how-do-i-determine-the-source-branch-of-a-particular-branch)

Comment: See also [How to determine when a Git branch was created?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2255416/1256452), in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3748722/1256452). The reflog entry showing the creation of the branch has useful information, provided it has not expired.