# Find first commit specific to a branch

Tags: git, branch

Looking for commits A(master), C(0.1), K(0.1.1) and O(0.2).

```
A - B - D - F - G   <- "master" branch (at G)
 \   \        
  \   C - E --M     <- "0.1" branch (still at E)
   \       \
    \       K - L   <- "0.1.1" branch (still at L)
     \
      O - P - F     <- "0.2" branch (still at F)
```

How can detect this commits by scripts without user data about parent branch.
In other words, how to determine the first commit (A, O, C, K), belongs to a particular branch, knowing only the name of this branch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In git, how can I find the revision at which a branch was created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058308/in-git-how-can-i-find-the-revision-at-which-a-branch-was-created)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
git log master..0.1
```

I think it should display commit C, E and M(is that a commit?)

Edit: The above works only if you have info about the parent branch.

New answer is to try the tool gitk

Comment: I need A, C, K and O. And i only know one branch and it will be in
program, i can't use master..0.1, because program don't know, that branch are parent for current.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the hash of first commit:

`git log <source_branch>..<feature_branch> --pretty=format:%h`