# Reset to the very first commit in Git?

Tags: git

Is there anything equivalent to the `--root` flag in the `rebase` command for the `reset` command?

```
git reset --root
```

Say I want to reset to the very first commit in my current branch: do I have to manually dig through the history and find the hash of that commit, or is there a simple way to reset to the first available commit?

Comment: And it seems silly running `git reset HEAD^` in a `while` loop.

Comment: Does these help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407526/git-how-to-find-first-commit-of-specific-branch and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git

Comment: @limelights Not quite the same thing, I'm looking for the **entirely** first commit, not the first commit since the branch diverged from the other branches.

Comment: @limelights However, using `rev-list` may be the answer (although the arguments would need to be tweaked greatly), so links were helpful, although not right on-topic.

Comment: great, they were meant as a pointer in the right direction :)

Answer (score 5):

A root commit (there can be more than one) is a commit with no parents.

This finds the root commit of the current commit (basically, "root of current branch" except that it works even with a detached HEAD):

```
git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD
```

This finds all root commits on all branches:

```
git rev-list --max-parents=0 --branches
```

and of course you can use `--tags` or `--all` instead of `--branches`.

Usually there's only one root in a repository so that all of these find the same revision, and `rev-list` prints revisions in a suitable order by default, so [manojlds' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23744832/1256452) will generally also work.

Edit: and of course, you have to provide the resulting SHA-1 to `git reset`.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
git reset --hard `git rev-list --all | tail -1`
```

Comment: This could pick the wrong root in a multi-rooted repository (e.g., git's own git repo).  (Note: it actually works there, at least if you're on any of the normal source chains; or did for me.  The roots of all other trees come out before the root of the main tree.)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find the a way within `git reset` but you would be able to reset to the initial commit of a repo with the following one-liner:

```
git log --pretty=format:%H | tail -1 | xargs git reset
```

Basically use `git log` to find the first commit and then using `xargs` you can reset back to it.