# Rebasing the very first commit

Tags: git, git-rebase

I was reading through the [documentation on rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History). It suggest rebasing by using `git rebase -i <hash>` but this does not work on the first commit of my project. **I want to split my very first commit into two commits and rename both of them but I am not sure how to rebase it.**

[This thread seemed relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744707/reset-to-the-very-first-commit-in-git) *but the answers provided there were not clear*. They state how to access the root commit but don't say how to access it in the context of a rebase. How do I rebase my very first commit in order to split it into two?

Answer (score 3):

As has been said, you can use the `--root` switch

```
git rebase -i --root
```

[Edit the root commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2119480/#14630424)