# What is the shorthand for "branch creation"?

Tags: git

I have a dev-branch, and I want to see the difference between "branch creation" and now. Actually, I'm more interested in the commit that followed the creation of the branch, which is more like "branch creation"+1.

I know I can use shorthand like HEAD and HEAD~1 in Git commands. I don't know how to specify "branch creation".

What is the Git shorthand for "branch creation" and "branch creation"+1?

Comment: Git does not record branch creation, in general. In some specific cases you may be able to find the commit ID in a reflog. Remember, as far as Git is concerned, branches are essentially irrelevant: only *commits* really matter. If you want a system that records branches forever, you don't want Git. If you are OK with "only commits matter", record specific commits using tags.

Comment: @torek I guess he means the closest point of intersection with some other branch. (if so, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549146/find-common-ancestor-of-two-branches))

Comment: git log master..branch --oneline | tail -1 , Read this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32870852/1270865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot see how a branch was created. This information is not saved. The branch points to a commit right now, and that's pretty much it. It is a very light weight object and very easy to set to point to some other commit, losing the history of the branch since creation.

Comment: I should have known there was no `TAIL` or similar given how poorly Git does with logging and branch support. I tried to get the question deleted but it was too late (there were already answers). I'm continually amazed at Git's penchant to take a simple task and make it difficult to impossible.

Answer (score 2):

There's a fundamental problem with your question: what exactly is "branch creation"?  A "branch" is just a pointer to a commit, which itself has a reference to a parent commit, which has a reference to a parent commit, and so forth backwards through time.

If I draw my git history like this:

```
a -> b -> c -> d (master)
      \
       -> x -> y (devbranch)
```

Then you might say the answer is obvious.  But the fact is that the history could also be drawn like this:

```
a -> b -> x -> y (devbranch)
     \
      -> c -> d
```

That's the same thing.  There is no specific "creation" of a branch; it's just a label applied to the tip of a chain of commits.

You *might* be able to get the answer you're looking for with the `merge-base` command, something like:

```
git checkout devbranch
git merge-base master HEAD
```

That will find "the best common ancestor(s) between two commits to use in a three-way merge," which in simple cases is probably going to be the point at which two branches diverge.

Answer (score 0):

you can use command as the following.

```
git diff topic...master
```

It means `Changes that occurred on the master branch since when the topic branch was started off it`

Quoted help of `git diff`

```
   git diff [--options] <commit>...<commit> [--] [<path>...]
       This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to
       the second <commit>, starting at a common ancestor of both <commit>. 
       "git diff A...B" is equivalent to 
       "git diff $(git-merge-base A B) B". You can omit any one of 
        <commit>, which has the same effect as using HEAD instead.
```

Also, you can see [Find the parent branch of a git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-git-branch) for how to find parent branch.

Comment: This works from the *merge base*, which, after a merge occurs, has nothing to do with the original branch creation. That *may* be what is desired after all (it's much more generally useful, for instance) but it's not what was asked-for. Other (non-Git) VCSes can and do provide what was asked-for, though at a price.