# Is there any way to check which was the last commit in a branch that exists in another one?

Tags: git

I have two branches: *master* and *feature*. I want to check which commit the *feature* branch was created from. To do this, I'm having to check each commit individually with

```
git branch -r --contains HEAD~X
```

which only returns both branches when I reach the desired commit. Is there any easier way to check this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407526/git-how-to-find-first-commit-of-specific-branch ?

Comment: not _exactly_ what I was searching for, but it **does** solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - how to find first commit of specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407526/git-how-to-find-first-commit-of-specific-branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if there's only a simple linear path from `feature` back to `master`, you're good with the accepted answer to [Git - how to find first commit of specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18407526):

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
    \
     E--F--G   <-- feature
```

Here `git log --oneline master..feature` will list commit `G`, then `F`, then `E`, so the last output line will be that for commit `E`.  (If you just want the hash ID, use `git rev-list master..feature | tail -1`.)

But consider:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
    \
     E   <-- develop
      \
       F--G   <-- feature
```

Here `master..feature` still lists commit `E`, even if you wanted commit `F`: you need `develop..feature` to have `git log` list `G` then `F` and then stop.

Or:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
    \
     \   F--G   <-- feature1
      \ /    \
       E      J--K  <-- feature3
        \    /
         H--I   <-- feature2
```

Here, commit `B` is shared by all branches; commit `E` is on all branches except `master`; `F` and `G` are shared by `feature1` and `feature3`; `H` and `I` are shared by `feature2` and `feature3`; and `J` and `K` are exclusive to `feature3`.

Using `master..feature3`, you'll enumerate commits `E` through `K`, but the *order* of, specifically, `F` through `I` is changeable.  (`E` will come out after all four, `F` will not be mentioned before `G` is listed, and `H` will not be mentioned before `I` is listed, but that still leaves a good number of possible orderings.)  You can choose the order, within limits, using the various sorting controls; the default is to go by committer date, when there are multiple possible commits for `git log` to emit at this point.

In general, Git works by starting at a *tip* commit, as pointed-to by one of these branch names, and working backwards.  When reaching a place where there's a join-up (like merge commit `J`), Git starts walking *both* paths at the same time.  With `git log`, it *prints* those commits in some order based on the sorting order you chose.  (Eventually the paths usually re-converge, as in this case they do at commit `E`.  At that point, `git log` can resume doing one commit at a time.)

The commits themselves are all fixed in place for as long as they exist—you can draw the graph a bit differently, but the parent of `E` is always `B`, for instance—but the *names*, the branch names that point to specific commits, are all moveable: any name can be moved at any time to point to any one specific commit.  Names can be added or deleted at any time, with one caveat: if you delete all the names that let you *find* a commit, it can be very hard to get that commit back.<sup>1</sup>  In general, Git commands and Git range listings like `A..B` and so on, resolve the names to the commits, then use the commit graph to do their job.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>If `git gc` runs at the wrong time, and you have reflogs disabled or the reflog entries are too old and stale, the <s>Grim</s> Garbage Collector can throw out any unreachable commit.  At that point, the commit is *really* gone, and even knowing its hash ID won't save you.

<sup>2</sup>The major exception here is `git diff`: if you give `git diff` a range, it just treats it as if you gave it two different commit hash IDs.  That is, `git diff A..B` does not walk the graph at all, it just finds `A` and `B` and then acts exactly like `git diff A B`.  The `git diff` command also has special treatment for the three-dot syntax, `A...B`.

`git rebase` has also acquired a special case for `A...B` (with three dots) in its `--onto` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using `git merge-base` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base).

`git merge-base master feature` will give you the first common ancestor. If you haven't merged `master` into `feature` since the initial creation of the `feature` branch, then this will give you the branching point.