# is there a way to find out where a branch came from?

Tags: git

is there a way to show like the tree structure for the branches created?

say i start from MASTER then to SONAR-VIOLATIONS then to PROJECT_ONE_VIOLATION, what is the command/method to show where the new branches branched from? in sort of a tree structure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto determine when a git branch was created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255416/howto-determine-when-a-git-branch-was-created)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the parent branch of a branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-branch)

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate of "Hotwo determine when...", which really does deal with when, i.e. what date, a branch was created.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the simplest solution would be `git log --graph` (better with `--oneline` and `--decorate` options).