# Git - Determine when a revision was pulled/fetched/merged at this site

Tags: git, revision

I know when certain commits were created (at remote *A*, say) based on their log messages. What I don't know is when remote *B* fetched and merged said revision. I need it to determine when a bug crept in.

Is this possible through Git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is `fetch`, try `git reflog --date=local`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3748722/88442 .
if it have a local merge, a git log would do.

Comment: I think all answers are good here, but reflog got me what I wanted. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have fetched the remote, you can simply check what branches on the remote contain the commit  by doing:

```
 git branch -r --contains <commit-SHA> | grep origin
```

You'll see the branches on the remote (change `origin` to the appropriate name) that contain the commit, or no output if none.

Answer (score 0):

Logs are kept in ".git/logs". You're probably interested in ".git/logs/HEAD" on the checkout you're interested in. These logs contain pulls, checkouts, commits, etc., along with the time they occurred.