# BitBucket Branch Creation Date

Tags: git, bitbucket

How can I get the branch creation date on BitBucket (STASH). 
I have one solution which is to clone the repository and issue the following command:
for k in `git branch|sed s/^..//`;do echo -e `git log -1 --pretty=format:"%Cgreen%ci %Cblue%cr%Creset" "$k"`\t"$k";done|sort

Which works, but I want another solution without using so much resources if you think about it...

I can't find anything in REST API.

Please HELP

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine when a Git branch was created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255416/how-to-determine-when-a-git-branch-was-created)

Comment: I don't see how the script you mention can show anything related to branch creation date. It rather shows time of last commit to a branch. What do you need actually?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?
I'd like to know if it's possible to obtain via REST api.

Comment: nothing about this is specific to bitbucket...

Answer (score 3):

Run this command in your branch which you want get first commit:

```
git log --all --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ad : %s" --date=iso
```

The format codes in the string have the following meaning:

```
%h - abbreviated commit hash
%an - Committer ID 
%ad - Date time.
```

Enjoy !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the git log --reverse to get the first commit and print its date.

Use the `--reverse` flag:

> ***`--reverse`***
>
> Output the commits in reverse order.

```
git log --reverse
```

If you only want the first commit add the `-n` flag to determine how many number of commits you want

```
 git log --reverse -n 1
```

Comment: what does commit date has got to do with branch creation date?