# How do I get the time of when a git checkout command was issued?

Tags: git

Is there a way to find what time a git checkout command was issued?

I did a git log but that is only showing me the commits. Not when I switched branches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine when a Git branch was created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255416/how-to-determine-when-a-git-branch-was-created)

Comment: Switching between already-created branches doesn't really *do* anything, so you won't be able to find that out.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Information about when a checkout occurred is stored *somewhere*, to allow commands like `git show HEAD@{5.minutes.ago}` to work.

Comment: @chepner oh right, interesting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog):

```
git reflog --pretty
```

Actually, it appears that the time shown via `reflog --pretty` is the time of the commit, but this will get you what I think you're looking for:

```
git reflog --date=iso
```