# Determine creation time of given branch with JGit

Tags: git, time, branch, jgit, creation

We have an application that is monitoring Git repositories using JGit. One of the current requirement is monitoring only files that have been created/modified after the branch was created (at least in the initial phase).

The idea was to get the time when the branch was created and synchronize only files which have been created later.

My question is if you know of any good idea to get time when the branch was created? Or maybe someone could suggest some other way to solve this issue based on their experience with JGit.

Comment: A branch (if you disregard its reflog, which is purely local) doesn't keep track of when it was created. Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24940131/2541573

Answer (score 3):

In git you cant know when a branch was created.
branch is only a pointer to a given commit.

What you can do you have to mark the branch in some way.

#### How can you mark branches?

Since you don't have a way to mark branches you can either tag the branch with a `git tag` or add a note using `git notes`

`git tag` will add a new tag to any given commit and you can add more than one tag to any commit.

`git notes` add notes to any git commit. The notes are not part of the commit and can be removed or modified without having any effect on the SHA-1

You can use git [`merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) to find out when the branch was **last updated**, not when it was created