# Find all branches on remote that have been created prior to a certain date

Tags: git

I need to remove the old branches on a git that have been left during the years and are on /feature or /hotfix branches... I need to remove all the one prior to october 2022. Is there a way to have the list of the branches with this criteria? or is there a visual tool that easily shows me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a list of Git branches, ordered by most recent commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188320/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-git-branches-ordered-by-most-recent-commit)

Comment: Just add cutoff date and filter by remote.

Comment: [How to determine when a Git branch was created?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2255416/7976758)