# git pulled branches history

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

*This is **NOT** duplicate ... Please read it thoroughly.*

If I am at branch `part-5` and I pulled 3 branches like

```
git pull origin part-1
git pull origin part-2
git pull origin part-3
```

Is there any command in git so that I can check that which branches I have pulled so far **into** `part-5`/current-branch ?

**NOTE:** I am **NOT** talking about creating I am talking about which branches are been pulled within current or `part-5` so far ... Just want the list of those branches. Hope you understand. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [find out when a git branch was created (not the first commit to that branch)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277841/find-out-when-a-git-branch-was-created-not-the-first-commit-to-that-branch)

Comment: I am **not** talking about creating I am talking about which branches are been pulled within current or `part-5` ... Just want the list of those branches .

Answer (score 0):

You can always execute `git fetch --all --prune` to update all your repo.

To view the current branches with the

```
* branch name
* date/commiter
* commit message
* author
```

`git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/heads/ --format='%(color:yellow)%(refname:short),%(color:bold green)%(committerdate:relative),%(color:blue)%(subject),%(color:magenta)%(authorname)%(color:reset)' | column -ts,`