# find point where two branches in git FIRST diverged

Tags: git, version-control, branch, branching-and-merging, dvcs

This is slightly simplified from the real story, but hopefully close enough.
Suppose I initially have one branch: develop.  Then I create a new branch: release.
At this point, release and develop both point to commit XYZ.
I do some work on the release branch, and occasionally merge it into develop.
Meanwhile, I do lots of other work on the develop branch.
Then one day I wake up and wonder when did my branches first diverge?
That is, I want to find the commit hash of commit XYZ.  The obvious temptation is to use "git merge-base" but this just finds the point when I last merged release into develop, which is WAY later than commit XYZ.

Comment: @RomainValeri AFAIU the question is not about branch labels but about commit's DAG: how to traverse the DAG starting with two branch heads back to the root commit finding the first (longest distance from both heads) commit where the arcs diverged.

Comment: As phd says, this should not require reflogs; this should in principle be derivable simply based on the current DAG and the current positions of develop and release branches.  I can even describe the commit I want semi-formally: I want the "latest" commit such that ALL of its ancestors are shared by both branches.

Comment: This seems to be a non-trivial task in general. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4991675/1725151) answer to “Finding a branch point with Git?”. Also see [this](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20230310214515.39154-1-felipe.contreras@gmail.com/) patch series which proposes an explicit representation as a ref/pointer.

Comment: thank you for both links!  indeed, if git explicitly tracked this info that would be ideal... I see a lot of that email thread is people discussing "how to maintain this info in the face of rebasing and such" but in the case that prompted this question, I know for a fact that the branch was never rebased.  So still super-useful even without accurate updates

Comment: Possibly relevant (caveat previous “this should not require reflogs”): [find when a branch was created using the reflog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18278195/1725151)

Comment: nice, but what if it wasn't create on my machine :)

Answer (score 3):

Since both branches have the same root, I think it should be possible to generate a list of commits back to the root commit for each branch, and then compare those two lists reversed until there is a difference. Then the common ancestor commit is the last one before the first difference.

The following command should then print the commit id of the common ancestor commit:

```bash
diff -u <(git log --reverse --oneline develop) <(git log --reverse --oneline release) \
   | sed '1,3d; /^[+-]/,$d' | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Edit: The sed argument is two delete (`d`) commands, separated with semicolon. The first delete is removing lines 1 to 3 (inclusive). The second delete is removing from the first line that starts with either plus or minus, until the last line (`$`).

Comment: care to explain the sed magic here?  or at least a hint as which part of the manual to look in?  (I don't know sed)

Comment: I think I get sed stuff now: we skip the first three lines, and then omit anything starting with a plus or minus, thus keeping only those lines that `diff` says are common to both.    Nice!  Surprisingly fast for something that walk whole history twice.  I think I prefer `--pretty=reference` instead of `--oneline` since dates help me stay oriented.  The one problem I see is that I think you shouldn't have `--reverse` above, since that gives us the most recent merge of release into dev, whereas I want to know where they first diverged.